# How to debug "error: cannot find symbol method" in Android code?

Tags: java, android, beacon

Why do I get these error's and how do I fix them...noob here please help?

```
error: cannot find symbol method getServiceUuid()
error: cannot find symbol method toByteArray()
error: cannot find symbol variable UrlBeaconUrlCompressor
```

Code:

```
beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

        // code to get URL below!!!!!
        for (Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {
            if (oneBeacon.getServiceUuid() == 0xfeaa && oneBeacon.getBeaconTypeCode() == 0x10) {
            // This is a Eddystone-URL frame
                String url = UrlBeaconUrlCompressor.uncompress(oneBeacon.getId1().toByteArray());
                Log.d("BeaconsEverywhere", "I see a beacon transmitting a url: " + url +
                            " approximately " + oneBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are, as you say, a noob, I recommend starting with simple material first. not only the success cases, also the failures, that 'll help you understand the error messages. Have you checked whether you have such a variable, whether it's a static method you call, whether the method(s) exist at all, whether your import is successful?

Answer (score 1):

As per the details you have provided I can see you are getting error of

Cannot find symbol method for following method

- toByteArray()
- getServiceUuid()

And class : UrlBeaconUrlCompressor

These class and methods belongs to Beacon Library, But in your code you are not able to access these Class and Methods, There could be two possible reasons :

- You have not imported related package : Check if you are importing them properly, Example :(If you are using altBeacon's [UrlBeaconUrlCompressor](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/beacon/utils/UrlBeaconUrlCompressor.html) )

  import org.altbeacon.beacon.utils.UrlBeaconUrlCompressor;
- You have not added dependencies properly in your build environment. Example :

  dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-proximitybeacon:v1beta1-rev38-1.25.0'}

or you might not have added dependencies for altbeacons

However I will recommend you to add proper log stacks and gradle dependencies with your question.

Comment: Thank You So much..that solved the prob with method getServiceUuid() and class UrlBeaconUrlCompressor...i added the dependencies and em now using the right library... implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'but im still having a prob with toByteArray()...its still red and cant find symbol...thanks for the start yr awesome!

Comment: got  toByteArray() to work had to restart catch in intellij...thank you!